# How to increment a state variable every second in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have a list of images in my code for this component called "url". I also have a state variable called `currImageIndex`. What I want to happen is every time this component is rendered, I would like to start a timer. Every second this timer runs, I would like to increment my state variable `currImageIndex`. When `currImageIndex + 1` is greater than or equal to `url` length, I would like to reset `currImageIndex` to zero. The overall goal is to simulate an automatic slideshow of images by just returning `<img src={url[currImageIndex]}>`. However, I am having issues with incrementing my state variable. I followed some code I found on here, but I can't figure out how to get the increment working. Here is my code.

```
const { url } = props;
  const [currImageIndex, setCurrImageIndex] = useState(0);
  console.log(url)
  const increment = () => {
    console.log(url.length)
    console.log(currImageIndex)
    if (currImageIndex + 1 < url.length) {
      setCurrImageIndex((oldCount) => oldCount + 1)
    }
    else {
      setCurrImageIndex(0)
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(increment, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.header}>Preview of GIF:</div>
      <img src={url[currImageIndex]} alt="GIF Preview" className={styles.image} />
      <div>{currImageIndex}</div>
    </div>
  );
```

When I run this with a `url` of size 2, the third to last line ("{currImageIndex}") displays the 1 then 2 then 3 and so on. It does not reset ever. My `console.log(url.length)` prints 2 and my `console.log(currImageIndex)` prints 0. What I want to happen is `currImageIndex` should be 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,.... Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is you've a stale enclosure of the `currImageIndex` state value from the initial render when the `increment` callback was setup in the interval timer. You're correctly using a functional state to increment the `currImageIndex`  value, but the `currImageIndex` value in the `increment` function body is and always will be that of the initial state value, `0`.

## Solution

A common solution here would be to use a React ref to cache the `currImageIndex` state so the current value can be accessed in callbacks.

Example:

```
const [currImageIndex, setCurrImageIndex] = useState(0);
const currentImageIndexRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  // cache the current state value
  currentImageIndexRef.current = currentImageIndex;
}, [currImageIndex]);

const increment = () => {
  // access the current state value
  if (currentImageIndexRef.current + 1 < url.length) {
    setCurrImageIndex((oldCount) => oldCount + 1)
  }
  else {
    setCurrImageIndex(0)
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  const id = setInterval(increment, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(id);
}, []);
```

A simpler solution is to just access the `url` value that is closed over in component scope with the state updater callback. Use a ternary operator to check if adding 1 to the current value is still less than the `url` length and state + 1, otherwise reset by returning `0`. Note however that if the `url` array is dynamic and the length changes this solution breaks for the same reason, the `url` value from the initial render is closed over in scope.

```
const increment = () => {
  setCurrImageIndex((count) => count + 1 < url.length ? count + 1 : 0);
}
```

And IMO the simplest solution is to just increment the `currImageIndex` state always and take the modulus of the `url` length to always compute a valid, in-range index value. If the `url` array changes, it doesn't matter as the modulus function will *always* compute a valid index.

```
const { url } = props;
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
const increment = () => setIndex(i => i + 1);

useEffect(() => {
  const id = setInterval(increment, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(id);
}, []);

const currImageIndex = index % url.length;

return (
  <div className={styles.container}>
    <div className={styles.header}>Preview of GIF:</div>
    <img src={url[currImageIndex]} alt="GIF Preview" className={styles.image} />
    <div>{currImageIndex}</div>
  </div>
);
```

[image: Edit how-to-increment-a-state-variable-every-second-in-react]

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the callback passed on setInterval only access the `currImageIndex` variable in the first render, not the new value while render so you will always get `currImageIndex = 0` and pass the condition `if (currImageIndex + 1 < url.length)`. I update your code and make it work like your expectation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y6fqwt